# URLSession instance method `downloadTask` error

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I've updated the [Advanced NSOperations](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/226/) sample app to Swift 3. The only remaining build error is on this snippet of code from the `DownloadEarthquakesOperation` class.

```
    let url = URL(string: "http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_month.geojson")!

    let task = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url) { (url, response, error) in
        self.downloadFinished(url, response: response, error: error)
    }
```

The error reads:

> Cannot invoke 'downloadTask' with an argument list of type '(with:
>   URL, (URL?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void)'
>
> Expected an argument list of type '(with: URL, completionHandler:
>   @escaping (URL?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void)'

This error doesn't make any sense to me as the `@escaping` attribute shouldn't affect the call site.
Any thoughts?

Comment: That does seem strange. What if you try without using trailing closure syntax? I.e. add the `completionHandler:` label and move it inside the )

Comment: @DaveWeston Tried that. Still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One line closures can often cause problems because the compiler is trying to infer the return type for the closure from whatever that one line in the closure returns. Theoretically it should be able to infer the correct type (because `downloadFinished` returns `Void`), but it looks like there are so many issues during the initial conversion of `AdvancedNSOperations` that it's just getting confused. You can silence that warning by adding an explicit `return` statement:

```
let url = URL(string: "http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_month.geojson")!

let task = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url) { url, response, error in
    self.downloadFinished(url, response: response, error: error)
    return
}
```

Frankly, once I finished the conversion (fixing all of the other issues), I was able to go back and remove that `return` statement and it was no longer a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try it in **Swift 3**:

```
let url = URL(string: "http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_month.geojson")!

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print(error!)
        return
    }
    // dosomething here
    print(data)

}).resume()
```

Hope it help!